# Convert SQL Returned date to DateTime Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I wonder if you can help me! I've searched the great answers of above and Google and alas i have been unable to find the answer to my conundrum!

Essentially I am running a SQL command from within PowerShell to retrieve the last restore Date Time however it is not displaying in a way that I (I think) cannot compare to the current date to see if the restore is consistent.

The script running is as per below:

```bsh
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=SERVER\Instance;Database=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "DECLARE @DB sysname = 'DataBaseName';
SELECT TOP 1 restore_date
FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory 
WHERE destination_database_name = @DB
ORDER BY restore_date DESC;"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$dbrestoredate = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
$SqlConnection.Close()
Write-Output "Database Restore date " $dbrestoredate
```

However this returns the format as "07 February 2017 09:15:30".

I'd much prefer this to be a standardized format e.g. `dd/mm/yyyy` so that I can compare that value to today's date and if it's a match do something.

If you have another way of doing the comparison that's fine by me, I just need to it to do something if the date returned is today's date.

Comment: Is this really the code you're running? Because at the moment, `$dbrestoredate` is first mentioned in the `Write-output` line, so I'm doubtful. All being well, a SQL Server `datetime` will be translated into a .NET `DateTime` struct without intervention, and without *any* formatting. Formatting only rears it's ugly head if you're converting this data into *strings*. Avoid the conversion, avoid the issues.

Comment: Apologies i amended the script to show more of what im trying to do and to help you guys understand my question better, also forgot to change "$DBName = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()" it should be $dbrestoredate instead of $dbname

Comment: Check the type of the returned data (`$dbrestoredate.GetType().FullName`). If it's `System.DateTime` then you can compare the value directly to other dates (e.g. the return value of `Get-Date` or `[DateTime]::Now`). You only want to format dates when you present them to a user. I strongly recommend *against* using `convert` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
select TOP 1 CONVERT(char(10), restore_date, 103) from msdb.dbo.restorehistory
```

This will return a string representing the date in the requested format (`dd/mm/yyyy`)

Please note that using `TOP x` without using `ORDER BY` is non-deterministic, since the order of the rows returned by the query can not be guaranteed unless using the `order by` clause.

Comment: Thank you so much! i could kiss both of you!  @McNets and Zohar thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

try converting it to string

```
select TOP 1 convert(varchar(20), restore_date, 103) as restore_date
```

Have a look at [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in MS Docs if you want to change final format.